# Multiprocessing, dynamic nested manager not working in windows (fine on Macs)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, dynamic, nested, multiprocessing

This is a vastly simplified version of running threads within threads where I call various groups of apis separately.Sometimes the groups will be run sequentially, sometimes simultaneously..below is the simplified code that works just fine on a mac:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def test(index):
    my_dict[index] = manager.dict()
    my_dict[index]['status'] = 200

def collate_tests():
    apis = []
    for i in range(10):
        apis.append(Process(target=test, args=(f"{i}",)))

for index, value in enumerate(apis):
    print (f"Execute {index +1} of {len(apis)} Tests")
    value.start()

for api in apis:
    api.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    my_dict = manager.dict()
    run_test = Process(target=collate_tests)

    run_test.start()
    run_test.join()

    for k,v in my_dict.items():
        print (k,v)
```

I get the result

```
0 {'status': 200}
1 {'status': 200}
2 {'status': 200}
4 {'status': 200}
3 {'status': 200}
5 {'status': 200}
6 {'status': 200}
7 {'status': 200}
9 {'status': 200}
8 {'status': 200}
```

In windows i get

```
NameError: name ‘my_dict’ is not defined
```

So I pass my_dict as args and then i get :

```
NameError: name ‘manager’ is not defined
```

If I pass manager as an arguments

```
TypeError : can’t pickle weakref objects
```

So i can't seem to set this line anyhow

```
my_dict = manager.dict()
```

I even tried instantiating another manager in the test() method. But that got me nowhere either as i couldn't iterate the dict proxy that created. Any suggestions?

Note the standard way of setting the nested managers in

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Is not feasible as I don't have any idea what 'index' my_dict[index] will be ahead of time. Is what I'm attempting even possible in Windows?

PS - I have scoured the web but didn't quite find the solution i was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Preforming the nested dictionary and assigning it to the key does the trick.

```
def test(index, my_dict):     
   nest = {}     
   nest['status'] = 200     
   my_dict[index] = nest
```